# chef install and update programs from source

Tags: ruby, deployment, chef-infra

I have a program that I build from source. For this I'm using the `script` resource. What is a good way to implement the logic for installation and update? Right now I just have installation implemented with the built-in `not_if` conditional.

```
script "install_program" do
  not_if {File.exists?('/program')}
  interpreter "bash"
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
    wget http://www.example.com/program.tar.gz
    tar -zxf program.tar.gz
    cd tarball
    ./configure
    make
    make install
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

First and foremost, if you have the means to host an internal package repository, I generally recommend that you build native packages for your target platform(s), and use the `package` resource to manage them, rather than building from source. I know that is not always available or feasible, so ...

The method which you make a "./configure && make && make install" style installation script idempotent depends on the kind of software you're working with. Most often, it is sufficient to check for the target file's existence. Sometimes, it is desirable to determine what version is required, and which version the program will output when executed with the proper command-line option.  I will use your resource above as a starting point for these examples. Note that you can use `bash` as a shortcut for `script` resources that have interpreter `bash`.

Assumptions: The program is installed to `/usr/local/bin/program` and takes an argument `--version` presumably to display the version number. I put the cd, configure, and make commands together with `&&` because presumably if one fails we shouldn't attempt to continue execution.

```
bash "install_program" do
  not_if "/usr/local/bin/program --version | grep -q '#{node[:program][:version]}'"
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
    wget http://www.example.com/program-#{node[:program][:version]}.tar.gz -O /tmp/program-#{node[:program][:version]}.tar.gz
    tar -zxf program-#{node[:program][:version]}.tar.gz
    (cd program-#{node[:program][:version]}/ && ./configure && make && make install)
  EOH
end
```

Instead of using `wget` it is a bit better to use the `remote_file` resource as this is idempotent on its own. Note that the `checksum` parameter is added, with the value as an attribute. This parameter tells Chef not to download the remote file if the local target file matches the checksum. This is a SHA256 checksum. Also, this resource will notify the script to run immediately, so after it is downloaded. The script is set with action `:nothing` so it only gets executed if the remote_file is downloaded.

```
remote_file "/tmp/program-#{node[:program][:version]}.tar.gz" do
  source "http://www.example.com/program-#{node[:program][:version]}.tar.gz"
  checksum node[:program][:checksum]
  notifies :run, "bash[install_program]", :immediately
end

bash "install_program" do
  user "root"
  cwd "/tmp"
  code <<-EOH
    tar -zxf program-#{node[:program][:version]}.tar.gz
    (cd program-#{node[:program][:version]}/ && ./configure && make && make install)
  EOH
  action :nothing
end
```

Also, `/tmp` may be erased on your system upon reboot. It is recommended that you download to another location that isn't deleted, such as Chef's file cache location, which is the value of `Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]`. For example:

```
remote_file "#{Chef::Config[:file_cache_path]}/program.tar.gz" do
  ...
end
```

For further examples, you can see "source" recipes in several cookbooks shared by Opscode here: http://github.com/opscode/cookbooks. `php`, `python`, `gnu_parallel`, and `nagios` cookbooks all have "source" recipes.

Comment: NOTE: A bug with ``remote_file`` can sometime ``ungzip`` a file with a ``.gz`` extension, like ``tar.gz``. So ``tar -zxf`` will fail because it is not really a gzip.

Comment: @jtimberman could you please explain more, where from `program` and `version` variable are set

Comment: they're arbitrary attributes i used as an example. They're set as node attributes. http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_node_object.html#attributes

Comment: I know this post is old, but how can you ensure that that the script doesn't run over an over again.  If it is installed from the /tmp folder then your trick for stopping the install occur again wouldn't work.

Comment: How can you ensure that the script runs at all?  Suppose when you run chef the first time that the `remote_file` resource succeeds but the `install_program` resource fails.  Then when you fix the issue and run chef again, the remote file is already present so it doesn't bother executing any actions on it, and it doesn't notify the `install_program` resource, so the program doesn't get installed.  I'd like to find a better pattern for installing software from source in chef.

Comment: Right, you really can't ensure it, or it's really hard because of the nature of what you're doing. Installing programs from source is very hard to make reliable and repeatable. That's why the first thing in my answer is that I suggest building packages and running an internal package repository. Package Cloud (packagecloud.io) is a great service that will do this for you for yum and apt repositories.